# How many data is needed to creat useful word vectors using gensim?

Tags: nlp, spacy, gensim, word2vec, named-entity-recognition

I try to do named entity recognition (nlp) on tweets for identifying if a tweet talks about diseases. For that purpose I'm currently try to create my own word2vec in gensim and import them for training a new ner model in spacy. My question would be, how many data is needed in order to create a useful word vector for my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

There's no fixed floor; it depends on your specific data/goals/parameters.

But the word2vec algorithm in general benefits from *lots* of data.

For word-tokens of interest, you'll want your training data to include many (at least dozens) realistic & subtly-contrasting examples of their usage in surrounding-word contexts.

The only real test of whether your data is sufficient: try it, tweak it, see if it gives useful results for your needs.